# Error: Please pass numbers as strings or BigNumber objects to avoid precision errors

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, truffle-test, bignumber

```
let result = await instance.joinQuiz({
    from: accounts[1],
    value: web3.utils.toWei(10, "wei")
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The signature of the toWei method is (can be found in the [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#towei).

```
web3.utils.toWei(number [, unit])

number - String|BN: The value.
unit - String (optional, defaults to "ether"): The ether to convert from.
```

So you should provide the number as either a String or a BigNumber (Web3 0.2x) / BN (Web3 1.x).

Your code should then be:

```
let result = await instance.joinQuiz({
    from: accounts[1], 
    value: web3.utils.toWei("10", "wei")
});
```

However, in your code you're converting from wei to wei, which might not be what you want, so keep in mind that the second parameter is the unit you're converting from.